# 100*300 の画像をアス比を維持したまま200*200にリサイズし余ったところを塗り潰した画像を再度作成したい

Tags: java, react-native

タイトル通りです。正確には、アンドロイド端末で起動された、react-nativeアプリからローカルの画像ファイルをピックし、それをアス比を維持したまま画像を指定のサイズにリサイズした画像を作成したいです。その際、リサイズしてできた余白を黒などで塗りつぶし、必ず指定したサイズで画像を作成したい。
そういった機能を持ったjavaのライブラリを探しています。

流れとしては、
react-native → ①画像ピック → ②ピックした画像をリサイズする → ③リサイズした画像をサーバーにアップロード

①のライブラリの目星はついていて、探しているのは②になります。
こういったワードで検索すると良いかも、的な回答もお待ちしております。

Answer (score 0):

[いい感じに画像をリサイズしてくれる React Component を作ってみた](http://sottar.hatenablog.com/entry/2017/05/21/171225)

上記で紹介されているソフトが要望を満たすのではないかと思います。
GitHubでソースコードも公開されていますから、ライブラリを作るのにも役立つと思われます。

Comment: 失礼、リサイズした画像の用途を記載していませんでした。サーバーにアップロードするため、コンポーネントではまずいです